# How to get the Guid value for any object i.e. [Page|Frame|JsHandle]

Tags: playwright

Is there a way to get the Guid value for the different objects?  Using C# looking at the various objects IPage, IFrame, and others objects, in the debugger there is the Guid, anyway to get the value?  Completely understand if the value might change at anytime, and willing to accept the risk if it does, would still like access to it...

[image: Guid for an IPage object]

Comment: what is your use-case for it? I'd recommend to open an issue in their repository with a story and details why you need it.

Comment: I have a page scraper to get an entire page, from what i'm seeing you don't get the url for the frame, and all the frame's page are the one page, so the one way to know if i've captured the frame from what i'm seeing is the GUID in the Frames collection.   And from what i see each of the frames do have a guid like "frame@<GUID>" but it is only accessible in the debugger but not public.

Answer (score 0):

The Playwright does not allow getting the GUID from such an object. These properties are private.

Therefore you cannot get such GUID. Maybe the best idea is to generate your own GIUDwith a getter

```
public string PageGuid => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, getting a unique Guid isn't the issue.

Without putting in lot of calls going back and fourth between the client<->server, looking for a way to know a <select> list's <option> values changed.  The list 'now' may have the same text/values as others.  Like words in a sentence.  Only using word count two different sentences, same word count, completely different words.  How to know the list has actually updated? Showing page@guid may not have been the best as i'd assert it is the actual list itself is what i'd like to know has been updated...